# addClass - LocalStorage Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, modernizr

I'm working on a site and want to store a class in localStorage although I'm having some problems.

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="type">
  <li id="1" class="current">Example 1</li>
  <li id="2">Example 2</li>
</ul>
```

I have some jQuery that adds a class to one of the examples when clicked.

When the class `current` is active, it changes some values on the site. Basically, when you visit the site, `#1` already has the class `current` but if I add the class the `#2`, I want `localStorage` to remember which element had the class `current`.

Here's what I've wrote so far of `localStorage` but I don't think it's right. (P.S. I'm using Modernizr).

```
function temp_type(){
  var type = $('.type li').hasClass('current');
}

$('#1').click(function() {
  $('#2').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
  if(Modernizr.localstorage) localStorage.setItem('temp_type'), $('.type li').hasClass('current');
});

$('#2').click(function() {
  $('#1').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
  if(Modernizr.localstorage) localStorage.setItem('temp_type'), $('.type li').hasClass('current');
});

if(Modernizr.localstorage){
  var type = localStorage.getItem('temp_type');
  if(type){
    $('.type li').hasClass('current');
    temp_type();
  }
}
```

Also, is there a way to test if `localStorage` is working or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be written in a simple way, try the below one

**HTML**

```
<ul class="type">
  <li id="1">Example 1</li>
  <li id="2">Example 2</li>
</ul>
<br />
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Check Storage</a>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.type li').on('click', function(event){
        $('.type li').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        if(Modernizr.localstorage){
            window.localStorage['temp_type'] = $(this).attr('id'); /*Storing the id of the selected element*/
        }
    });

    $('a').on('click', function(event){ 
        alert(window.localStorage['temp_type']); /*Check the current storage*/
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
li.current {
    color: red;
}
```

**Demo JS** http://jsfiddle.net/5vmBe/3/

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This helps a lot thanks! How can I change a value if an element has `.current` though? Would it be something like `if ($('#2').hasClass('current')) { $('body').append('<div>yay!</div>');` }?

Comment: I didn't get it. Do you want to change the value of the local storage? In that case, the value can be changed only on click of the 'li' element.